# How to create bitwise mask in node.js by byte numbers?

Tags: node.js, bitwise-operators

I have a string: `0x55739dC6385d81c53d462a255a17C6bd9A71Aa68`.

And also I have a function that I need to implement:

```
const caller = '0x55739dC6385d81c53d462a255a17C6bd9A71Aa68';
const from = 160;
const to = 96;

const getCallerMask = (from, to, caller) => {
    // need to get mask by from, to on the "caller" string and move bytes to the right by "to" argument
}
```

This is what the function should do:

```
Mask(160, 96, caller) >> 96
```

I don't even know in which language the example above, but I guess that it should take the byte mask from the string and move the pointer to 96 bytes to the right. Is there a way to implement it in node.js?

Comment: your function has 3 arguments, which one is `0x55739dC6385d81c53d462a255a17C6bd9A71Aa68`?

Comment: considering you have a hexadecimal value in form of a string, I think you should first convert it to a bytes array. And then (I guess) you have to convert it to bits, since MASK (or bitmasking) is used for bitwise operations.

Comment: this fiddle might be a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/vLuqgrzj/ result is a 20 bytes array. Which is 160 bits long.

Comment: "but I guess that it should take the byte mask from the string and move the pointer to 96 bytes to the right"  I think those are 96 bits (12 bytes)